# why is otherwise callback / catch block not getting executed?

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

I am working with tableau JS API and using the `getParametersAsync()` method which return all the parameters on a workbook and there seems to be a exception when doing so.

The exception I am getting "Duplicate key 'OperatorTypeParameter'", however my `otherwise` callback does not get executed, I also tried to add a try / catch but the execution flow does not come in the outer catch as well as the inner catch block.

```
try {  
  workbook.getParametersAsync().then(function(parameter) {}).otherwise(function(err) {  
    try {  
      console.log(err);  
    } catch(e) {  
      console.log(e)  
    }  
  });  
} catch(e) {  
  console.log(e)  
}
```

Not sure if it's a bug in the API. Any help in this would be really great.

Thanks.

Comment: is this you? https://community.tableau.com/thread/327677

Comment: Hi @GrafiCode, yes